# shell script to execute a nohup task inside a docker

Tags: shell, docker

[referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287859/nohup-commands-from-inside-shell-script-are-blocking-script-exeuction)
Tried the following, to execute the below nohup commands inside a container,

```
nohup sh $KAFKA_HOME/bin/connect-standalone.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/connect-standalone-mongo.properties $KAFKA_HOME/config/connect-mongo-sink.properties &

nohup /bin/bash $KAFKA_HOME/bin/connect-standalone.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/connect-standalone-mongo.properties $KAFKA_HOME/config/connect-mongo-sink.properties &
```

And tried the below as well,

```
declare -a parameters=( "/opt/kafka/config/connect-standalone-mongo.properties" "/opt/kafka/config/connect-mongo-sink.properties")
for parameter in "${parameters[@]}"
do
   echo  "$1"  > "/tmp/test02.txt"
   nohup   /bin/sh $KAFKA_HOME/bin/connect-standalone.sh -p   $parameter 1> ${parameter}_nohup.out 2> ${parameter}_nohup.err &
    #message received
    echo  "$1"  > "/tmp/test03.txt"
done[referred the following link as well][1]
```

when I tried the below I am getting and empty out file,
$(nohup .$KAFKA_HOME/bin/connect-standalone.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/connect-standalone-mongo.properties $KAFKA_HOME/config/connect-mongo-sink.properties > out.txt  &)

Comment: what else should check,,

Comment: Generally I'd expect to see Kafka Connect running as the single (foreground) process in a different container.  You don't typically run background processes in containers, especially long-running servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below way of scripting works for me!!!!!!!!!

```
ex=' /opt/kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh /opt/kafka/config/connect-standalone-mongo.properties  /opt/kafka/config/connect-mongo-sink.properties > /opt/kafka/kafka-mongo-info.out 2> /opt/kafka/kafka-mongo-error.err &'

while true
  do

    # nohup $ex 1> nohup_kms.out 2> nohup_kms.err | tee -a /var/log/my_uber_script.log
    # nohup $ex 1> nohup_kms.out 2> nohup_kms.err

  done
```

you can try  any one inside the loop